# Video live broadcasting for xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, broadcast, live-streaming

Is there any live broadcasting mechanism in xamarin forms?
Any plugins or any native codes? I wanted it for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Plugin.MediaManager.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.MediaManager.Forms/) plugin for this purpose. Additionally you must have a source broadcasting.

A video app needs a window for viewing content. For this reason, a video app is usually implemented on a single screen.

```cs
CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4", MediaFileType.Video);
```

And in your view like this:

```xml
<forms:VideoView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Source="YourVideoFile" AspectMode="AspectFill" />
```

Here is source code for this plugin: https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager

More information on the [Xamarin Blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/).

Comment: Hi, I wanted to do a live video recording plugin... The player at the end which is for viewing can be used as MediaManager. But the live recording part is the where I am stuck

Comment: Hi can you please let me know, other than Plugin.MediaManager.Forms, any other ways for live video recording and broadcasting. I have enquired James regarding live video recording using MediaManager.Forms plugin and he told its not possible with that. Using it we can record and save video... Any other details can you provide please?

Comment: did any of you get any answer ? the plugin does not handle streaming videos or M3U8 formats. does anybody knows any approach to this.